# Getting Height of iframe within Same Domain

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe with source of another content within the same domain. The content is dynamic and may grow from time to time (contains users comments). I am displaying this iframe inside a modal. 
I am trying to get the height of the iframe content so that I can shrink the iframe height in the modal accordingly. I found several solutions online but non of them I could understand. What is the easiest way to go over it? I enabled scrolling in iframe which solved the problem, however, it just does not look good showing the scrollbar inside the modal. 
Note that I am using the Scrolling modal in Semantic-ui (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/examples) and inserted the iframe inside the description div, expecting iframe will just shrink in height too. But obviously it did not and I am assuming I need to figure out a way to find iframe height.

Comment: Sorry. I mean within the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script on my page and it's working. I also added another part of script with a delay for the first time I load the page it have enougth time to resize.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<iframe src="my-page" frameborder="0" id="foo" onload="autoResize('foo')"></iframe>
```

And the script.

```
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height=(newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width=(newwidth) + "px"; 
}
```

Test it and let me know if it worked for you.